# Set small_image to exclude

Tags: magento-enterprise, product-images

I have imported images using a 3rd party import tool.

I'm importing several files and one sets the `small_image` flag the tool does not allow me to flag exclude.

The problem is we don't want the small image to show on the product page as in about 50% of our products it will be a duplication.

Is there a way either in the database or via a script that will allow me to set all images that are small images to exclude ?

Any help would be welcome

Comment: Have you given label to your small images?

Comment: No, but I could if its the only way to exclude it

Answer (score 0):

Ok first upload those small images with **same label**.

Then run this code in `sql`

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value 
SET disabled = 1
WHERE label = 'your_small_image_label'
```

This should set your all small image to **Exclude**.

Generally we are going to `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` table and setting all item having label as `your_small_image_label`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thinking about it we don't want the alt text to be the same label on the cat pages. is there a way to to look at the small image flag in the DB ?

Thanks

Comment: You can change alt text for small images to product title with prefix or something else later in catalog/view/media.phtml